# Linq to SQL Querying Column with spaces in column Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

Using Linq to SQL

How does one query and match to include all rows from a secondary table with a column that contains spaces in column?

Table 1:

```
ID  FAQ    MODELS 
1   faq1   model1 
2   faq2   model2 model1
3   faq3   model3 model2 model1   (Spaces in models column)
```

Table 2:

```
ID  MODELS PIC
1   model1 model1pic
2   model2 model2pic
3   model3 modal3pic
```

Expecting:

```
faq1 model1 model1pic
faq2 model1 model1pic
faq2 model2 model2pic
faq3 model1 model1pic
faq3 model2 model2pic
faq3 model3 model3pic


SELECT kwfaqtmp.faqmodelnum, kwFAQtmp.issue,
kwfaqtmp.resolution, kwtable4tmp.modelnum,     
kwtable4tmp.prodpic 
FROM kwfaqtmp AS t1 CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(t1.faqmodelnum, ' ') AS s 
INNER JOIN dbo.kwtable4tmp 
AS t2 ON s.item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = t2.modelnum 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
ORDER BY t1.issue;
```

Comment: Are you talking about splitting the column data?

Comment: Correct! I Just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't fix the design (you shouldn't be storing multiple pieces of data in a single column, as pointed out elsewhere), you can accomplish this with a split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
  @List  NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delim NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM
       ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
         FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'
         + REPLACE(@List, @Delim, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
           ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
       WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO
```

Now you can say:

```
SELECT t1.FAQ, t2.MODELS, t2.PIC
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(t1.MODELS, ' ') AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
ON     s.Item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
  = t2.Models COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ORDER BY t1.FAQ;
```

Results:

```
FAQ   MODELS  PIC
----  ------  ---------
faq1  model1  model1pic
faq2  model1  model1pic
faq2  model2  model2pic
faq3  model1  model1pic
faq3  model2  model2pic
faq3  model3  modal3pic
```

The query you tried to use:

```
 SELECT kwfaqtmp.faqmodelnum, kwFAQtmp.issue,kwfaqtmp.resolution, 
    kwtable4tmp.modelnum, kwtable4tmp.prodpic 
 FROM kwfaqtmp AS t1 
 CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(t1.faqmodelnum, ' ') AS s 
 INNER JOIN dbo.kwtable4tmp AS t2 
   ON s.item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
     = t2.modelnum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
 ORDER BY t1.issue;
```

Is simply not valid. Though it shouldn't yield the exact error you cite in the comment. How about keeping the t1 / t2 aliases as my original query showed?

```
 SELECT t1.faqmodelnum, t1.issue, t1.resolution, 
    t2.modelnum, t2.prodpic 
 FROM kwfaqtmp AS t1 
 CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(t1.faqmodelnum, ' ') AS s 
 INNER JOIN dbo.kwtable4tmp AS t2 
   ON s.item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
     = t2.modelnum COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
 ORDER BY t1.issue;
```

Comment: Not Automatic.  LINQ squeels and complains not being able to convert to appropriate sql command

Comment: If you are using the Linq2SQL designer (open the .dbml file) you can specify the Source property in the Properties Window. Something like dbo.[foo bar] should suffice I would think.

Comment: No I'm referring to the data within column.

Comment: @Aaron I agree, of course this is what I inherited so. (sigh)  Anyways...giving this a test run....be back in a couple of mins...

Comment: @Aaron **Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.** When Running Split Function

Comment: Please try now. Why do you have mixed collation?

Comment: The collation is gone now i get this: **The multi-part identifier "T1.models" could not be bound. **

Comment: Is your collation case sensitive? If you look closely at my query, I don't say `T1` anywhere... only `t1`. If your server is case sensitive you need to be careful about how you reference tables, columns, aliases, etc. especially if you're going to sloppily re-write code provided to you by a volunteer. If this is not the case, then please post your ***ACTUAL*** query in the question (not as a comment: *impossible to read*). I can't reverse engineer the problem given only an error message that clearly doesn't belong to the only version of the query that I can see.

Comment: Query has been included in question.

Comment: Closed? I'm getting used to the editor and made a mistake inserting the code section.  Can you reopen it??

Comment: I'm not the one who closed it. Anyway I can see your edit and will add it to my answer.

Comment: Nice!!  Thanks with your corrections I also understand where I messed up in translating to the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx) in your mapping class. 
Create a POCO class with fieldnames without spaces, mapped to the ones with spaces in your table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to refactor your database.

```
FAQ (remove MODELS column)

ID  FAQ
1   faq1
2   faq2
3   faq3

FAQMODELS (Create this table)
ID FAQ   MODELS
1  faq1  model1
2  faq2  model2
3  faq2  model1
4  faq3  model3
5  faq3  model2
6  faq3  model1

MODELSPIC    
ID  MODELS PIC
1   model1 model1pic
2   model2 model2pic
3   model3 modal3pic
```

Then you can

```
SELECT
    FAQ, 
    MODELS, 
    PIC 
FROM FAQMODELS INNER JOIN MODELSPIC ON FAQMODELS.MODELS = MODELSPIC.MODELS
```

Comment: I'm going to take your recommendations for future projects..

Comment: By the way anyone have an applicable script to automate this??